# How to organize MVP with an IoC container?

Tags: .net, winforms, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to get the IoC concept down with a winforms app. Say I have  a presenter whose constructor takes its view and a service as constructor arguments. So in the form code I have something that amounts to this:

```
mnPresenter = new Presenter(this, new AppService());
```

where, say AppService is an implementation of IAppService. It's registered in my `[autofac]` IoC container. What's the recommended way of getting the "new" out of this presenter construction? Isn't the whole point of using an IoC framework to lose these "new" calls like I'm making above?

I could do something like

```
mPresenter = new Presenter(this, MyContainer.Resolve<IAppService>())
```

but that seems to defeat the purpose of IoC. I'm probably missing something fundamental here.

Apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that there is a dependency cycle between the View and the Presenter, since they depend on each other. The general rule in breaking this dependency cycle is to fallback to property injection, which will work in your case as well.

With MVP, best is to let the View assign itself to a created Presenter by injecting it into a property of the Presenter:

```cs
mPresenter = container.Resolve<Presenter>();
mPresenter.View = this;
```

If you can, hide the container from the application. Since you are using MVP, the only things you'll ever need to directly resolve are presenters. So instead of letting the Forms communicate with the Container, let them communicate with a static `PresenterFactory`. This factory will use the container under the covers:

```
mPresenter = PresenterFactory.Create<MyPresenter>();
mPresenter.View = this;
```

Your `PresenterFactory` might look like this:

```
public static class PresenterFactory
{
    private static IContainer container;

    public static TPresenter Create<TPresenter>()
        where TPresenter : IPresenter
    {
        return (TPresenter)
            container.Resolve(typeof(TPresenter));
    }

    public static void SetContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        PresenterFactory.container = container;
    }
}
```

And your Composition Root might look like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Bootstrap();
}

private static void Bootstrap()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // TODO: register presenters

    var container = builder.Build();

    PresenterFactory.SetContainer(container);
}
```

*UPDATE*

Perhaps even better would it be to do something like this:

```
interface IPresenter<TView>
{
    TView View { get; set; }
}

public static class PresenterFactory
{
    private static IContainer container;

    public static IPresenter<TView> CreateForView<TView>(TView view)
    {
        var presenter = container.Resolve<IPresenter<TView>>();
        presenter.View = view;
        return presenter;
    }
}

// View
mPresenter = PresenterFactory.CreateForView(this);
```

This hides the actual implementation of the presenter from the view and centralizes the registration of the view to the presenter.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. Thanks for getting back to me, Steven, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just put your suggestion into play and like the way it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Many thanks for this tip, just helped me out of a bit of a situation ;)

Comment: If you happen to be using Autofac for this and are having trouble registering your open generics, you're not alone: there is a discussion about it [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/215).

Answer (score 1):

You need a property in the presenter

```
public IAppService service;
```

and it will be injected by the container, you don't need to pass it as a parameter. What you wrote is a service locator, in fact an anti-pattern for IoC.

If your view is strongly typed and registered with the container too, you can use .SingleInstance lifecycle of Autofac and a property

```
public IMyView view;
```

in your presented, the container will then inject the view instance into your presenter.

You basically look the code in another question:
[Register a Presenter with a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078640/register-a-presenter-with-a-view)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I might know what you're talking about, but if you have the time a code sample, even a brief one, would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Rob, there's a link in my reply, last line.

Comment: OK, thanks. I misread your answer. I thought you were using that link as an illustration of what NOT to do. I appreciate you getting back to me again.