# Register a Presenter with a View

Tags: c#, mvp, autofac

If I have a presenter like this -

```
public class LandingPresenter : ILandingPresenter
{            
    private ILandingView _view { get; set; }
    private IProductService _productService { get; set; }

    public LandingPresenter(ILandingView view, IProductService)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

How do I register this Presenter with Autofac considering the dependent view will not be registered (but IProductService will)

```
    builder.RegisterType<LandingPresenter>().As<ILandingPresenter>(); ????
```

Comment: What do you mean by "view will not be registered"? You want to provide it explicitly or..?

Comment: Sorry yes, in the View I would construct the Presenter like so - Presenter = new LandingPresenter(this); (the IProductService would get injected using Autofac factories)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not register the views in the container as well, put Autofac to work! Then you can hook up presenters and views automagically by using constructor injection on the presenters and property injection on the views. You just have to register the views with property-wiring:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly).
    Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("View")).
    PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringFlags.AllowCircularDependencies).
    AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Presenter:

```
public class LandingPresenter : ILandingPresenter
{            
    private ILandingView _view;
    private IProductService _productService { get; set; }

    public LandingPresenter(ILandingView view, IProductService _productService)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

View:

```
public class LandingView : UserControl, ILandingView
{
    // Constructor

    public LandingView(... other dependencies here ...)
    {
    }

    // This property will be set by Autofac
    public ILandingPresenter Presenter { get; set; }
}
```

And if you want to go view-first then you should be able to reverse it so the presenters take the view as property instead.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response! I wired it up as you have posted however I get an error :( --- Cannot resolve parameter 'Views.Landing.ILandingView view' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Views.Landing.ILandingView, .... It seems as though Autofac still doesn't know what to do with the parameter ILandingView I have double checked Autofac is registering the correct assembly any ideas?

Comment: It means that the view LandingView (as an ILandingView implementor) hasn't been registered. If you use the builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes when you create your Autofac and make sure that the parameter (ThisAssembly in my example) points to the assembly that contains the views, it should work.

Comment: I have now got passed this error but now when loading the Landing.aspx page the instance of the view is injected into the controller which is not going to work because it is a different instance than the one which is created on page load. This will then cause object not set to an instance on basically all properties in the view... :(

Comment: Then your initial question has got an answer, consider accepting it. From your previous posts it's not clear that the framework in question is ASP.NET Webforms. Look here for information about Autofac WebForms integration: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration and here for a proposed solution for MVP/MVC in WebForms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff955232.aspx.