# How to Create Winforms Generic Presenter Factory with IoC

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, simple-injector

I'm creating a Winforms application using the MVP design pattern. Currently, I create a view, and then in the view's constructor I inject the presenter for the view. However, in order to use an IoC container, I've got to break the dependency cycle between the view and the presenter. My situation is similar to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706620/how-to-organize-mvp-with-an-ioc-container)

The difference, however, is that my main form has multiple presenters. So, I'm trying to set up a presenter factory where I can more specifically specify a presenter interface type on which to create a presenter instance. And, I'd like the factory to be able to set the view property of the presenter. I'm a little new to generics, so I'm failing a little bit here. Here is my failing code so far:

```
public interface IPresenter<TView>
{
    TView View { get; set; }
}

public static class PresenterFactory
{
    private static Container _container;

    public static void RegisterContainer(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public static IPresenter<TView> CreatePresenterForView<TPresenter, TView>(TView view)
        where TPresenter : IPresenter<TView>
    {
        var presenter = _container.GetInstance<TPresenter>();
        presenter.View = view;
        return presenter;
    }
}
```

The error is coming from where I'm trying to get the instance from the container. It says TPresenter must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter.

Any suggestions on what to do here?

**Edit (answering a question as to why I have multiple presenters for one view)**: Well, that is a good question, and I'm not convinced in my answer. I have a large main form with a lot of functionality, but I want all of that functionality on a single screen. Thankfully, the functionality can be loosely grouped into related areas. So, to manage the complexity of the view, I created a bunch of partial class files, each one dedicated to one of the functional areas (say I have 5 functional areas). I also have an interface for each of the functional areas of the view. Essentially, in each partial class file I implement one of the interfaces:

```
partial class MainView : Form

partial class MainView : IMainViewFunctionalArea1
```

My plan was to have a separate presenter for each of the functional areas, and each presenter would have a reference to the MainView via an interface:

```
class PresenterMainViewFunctionalArea1
{
    IMainViewFunctionalArea1 view;

    ...
}
```

And yes, I'm realizing this doesn't match with the initial code I posted. But hey, I'm learning! The thought was that this would simplify testing by separating it out this way. The presenter would only have methods related to its functional area, and the view interface would only expose relevant stuff.

All that said, I'm now thinking about what it would be like to have just one presenter, probably separated into partial classes the way I do my view. The presenter could implement interfaces for all the functional areas, and then testing could simplified based off what interface is used.

I could use some guidance here guys!

Comment: Have you tried it with `public interface IPresenter<TView> where TView : class` and `public static IPresenter<TView> CreatePresenterForView<TPresenter, TView>(TView view) where TPresenter : IPresenter<TView> where TView : class` ? class could be an Interface with a View property aswell.

Comment: What would be the type of the View property on the new class?

Comment: @Jannik is right. You need to add the `where TPresenter : class` generic type constraint to the `CreatePresenterForView` method, because Simple Injector's `GetInstance<T>` method contains this constraint as well.

Comment: @Andrew: It would be the type `TView` that you used for the class. Example: For `public class MyViewPresenter : IPresenter<MyView>` would need a property `View` with the type `MyView`

Comment: "The difference, however, is that my main form has multiple presenters" => can you elaborate this? Why does the main form has multiple presenters?

Comment: Hey Ric, I edited my initial post to add an answer to your question. Thank you for everybody's responses so far!

I'm also pretty stoked to see Steven answering. He created/contributes to Simple Injector (the container I'm starting to use), and his [blog](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/index.php) has helped immensely in planning out the query/command side of my application. So, thanks for all the help you don't know you've given me.  :)